# SWIG Generating LUA wrappers for C functions - Need help to find/use constructor and attribute setting methods of C types and structures

Tags: c, automation, lua, wrapper, swig

I am having trouble with type manipulation through the LUA interpretor of an Embedded Linux machine.

To summarize my problem I am developping drivers in C that need to be tested on a specific device.
For this I have a Linux image running on my target with a LUA interpretor that I chose to call unitarely all the different functions.

Thus I am generating a **LUA wrapping interface of my C function** with **SWIG** (Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator).

For my problem I'll stick with only my UART module.

The SWIG interface we is is quite basic, it only includes the different .h files of the project :

```
%module UartLuaWrapper
%include <hdswErrorManagement.h>
%include <hdswOther.h>
%include <hdswUart.h>
%include <hdswWaiter.h>
%include <hwAccess.h>
%include <macrosUtil.h>
%include <typesGeneral.h>
%include <typesGeneralPPC.h>
%include <config.h>
%include <typesGeneralPPC.h>
```

I generate the wrapper through the following command :
`swig -lua -I../hdsw/include -o wrapUART.c wrapUART.i`

to get this file :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hL3bM65nxdEPQHx_GY8STM7MF0Wh_KyC/view?usp=sharing

I then build and link with the following command (simplified here as it's quite long with many options) :
`powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -shared wrapUART.c -o UARTLuaWrapper.so -lHDSW` (with other target specific options such as -me500v2 -fPIC -mbig-endian -m32)

which gives me a shared object (.so) that I can require in LUA.
The content of this .so file as loaded in LUA gives the following table is the following:

```
['UartLuaWrapper'] = {
        ['FORMAT_X64'] = '%016I64X',
        ['C_EMPTY'] = 0,
        ['E_HDSW_UART_MPC'] = 0,
        ['hdswErrorPerformGetCode'] = 'function: 0xf5d1648',
        ['E_HDSW_UART_LIPA'] = 1,
        ['C_FULL'] = 0,
        ['t_hdswUart_Tx_Edac_2E_Cnt'] = {
        },
        ['FORMAT_I64'] = '%I64d',
        ['hdswErrorPerformGetInterface'] = 'function: 0xf5d1310',
        ['C_LITTLE_ENDIAN'] = 1,
        ['hdswUartRead'] = 'function: 0xf5b6060',
        ['E_HDSW_UART_9600'] = 0,
        ['E_HDSW_UART_115200'] = 1,
        ['C_YES'] = 1,
        ['hdswErrorPerformGetService'] = 'function: 0xf5d14a8',
        ['C_BIG_ENDIAN'] = 0,
        ['E_HDSW_UART_7BITWORD'] = 3,
        ['E_HDSW_UART_2BITSTOP'] = 1,
        ['hdswUartMonitor'] = 'function: 0xf5b5dd0',
        ['t_hdswUart_Rx_Edac_1E_Cnt'] = {
        },
        ['hdswUartWrite'] = 'function: 0xf5d60a0',
        ['t_hwAccessor'] = {
        },
        ['hdswUartInit'] = 'function: 0xf5b63d0',
        ['E_HDSW_UART_1000000'] = 4,
        ['t_hwAccessClass'] = {
        },        
        ['PATH_SEPARATOR'] = '\',
        ['t_hdswUart_Tx_CstsRegUnion'] = {
        },
        ['t_hdswUart_Tx_Csts'] = {
        },
        ['E_HDSW_UART_230400'] = 2,
        ['E_HDSW_UART_6BITWORD'] = 2,
        ['hdswUartEnableIt'] = 'function: 0xf5d6634',
        ['C_FALSE'] = 0,
        ['E_HDSW_UART_5BITWORD'] = 1,
        ['hdswErrorPerformGetLocation'] = 'function: 0xf5d17e8',
        ['C_NOT_EMPTY'] = 1,
        ['E_HDSW_UART_460000'] = 3,
        ['t_int8uToInt16u'] = {
        },
        ['t_int8uToInt16u_bytes'] = {
        },
        ['hdswUartPerformState'] = 'function: 0xf5d63d4',
        ['C_TRUE'] = 1,
        ['C_NO'] = 0,
        ['t_hdswUart_Tx_Edac_1E_Cnt'] = {
        },
        ['t_hdswUartBlindClass'] = {
        },
        ['E_HDSW_UART_EVEN'] = 0,
        ['t_int16uToInt32u_halfwords'] = {
        },
        ['C_ENDIANNESS'] = 0,
        ['t_int16uToInt32u'] = {
        },
        ['t_hdswUart_Rx_Csts'] = {
        },
        ['C_BIT_NOT_SET'] = 0,
        ['hdswUartPerformCallBack'] = 'function: 0xf5b5b38',
        ['t_int32uToInt64u_words'] = {
        },
        ['E_HDSW_UART_8BITWORD'] = 4,
        ['t_int32uToInt64u'] = {
        },
        ['t_hdswUart_Rx_Cnt'] = {
        },
        ['E_HDSW_UART_ODD'] = 1,
        ['hdswErrorDataGetNthLastPushedDatum'] = 'function: 0xf5d1988',
        ['t_hdswUart_Tx_Cnt'] = {
        },
        ['t_hdswUart_Rx_CntRegUnion'] = {
        },
        ['E_HDSW_UART_NOPARITY'] = 2,
        ['t_hdswUart_Tx_Edac_2E_CntRegUnion'] = {
        },
        ['C_BIT_SET'] = 1,
        ['hdswOtherInit'] = 'function: 0xf5b7b20',
        ['t_hdswUart_Rx_CstsRegUnion'] = {
        },
        ['E_HDSW_UART_LIPA'] = 1,
        ['t_hdswUart_Tx_Edac_1E_CntRegUnion'] = {
        },
        ['t_hdswUart_Rx_Edac_2E_CntRegUnion'] = {
        },
        ['C_NOT_FULL'] = 1,
        ['E_HDSW_UART_1BITSTOP'] = 0,
        ['t_hdswUart_Rx_Edac_1E_CntRegUnion'] = {
        },
        ['hdswUartDisableIt'] = 'function: 0xf5d68c0',
        ['t_hdswUartConf'] = {
        },
        ['t_hdswUartMonitor'] = {
        },
        ['t_int16uToInt32u'] = {
        },
        ['hdswErrorPerformGetLocation'] = 'function: 0xf5d17e8',
 
        ['E_FILER_PID_MASK_MATCHES'] = 0,
        ['t_hdswUart_Rx_Edac_2E_Cnt'] = {
        },
        ['FORMAT_U64'] = '%I64u',
        ['t_hdswUart_Tx_CntRegUnion'] = {
        },  
        ['E_HDSW_UART_1BITSTOP'] = 0
},
```

Methods and const seem to be properly loaded, but the wrapped types are all empty tables, for exemple :

```
> UartLuaWrapper.t_hdswUartConf
table: 0x100aace0
> ipairs(UartLuaWrapper.t_hdswUartConf)
function: 0x10023774    table: 0x100aace0       0
> pairs(UartLuaWrapper.t_hdswUartConf)
function: 0x100235a8    table: 0x100aace0       nil
> #UartLuaWrapper.t_hdswUartConf
0
> UartLuaWrapper.t_hdswUartConf()
<userdata of type 't_hdswUartConf *' at 0x100b1000>
> print(UartLuaWrapper.t_hdswUartConf)
table: 0x100aace0
> print_r.print_table(UartLuaWrapper.t_hdswUartConf)
{

}
```

I am expecting setters and getters there, and a new_XXX method or something.
Whould anyone know why it is empty? Did I miss something? Has anyone encountered such issue?

In SWIG generated source file I find such declarations :

```
static swig_lua_namespace swig_SwigModule = {
    "UartLuaWrapper",
    swig_SwigModule_methods,
    swig_SwigModule_attributes,
    swig_SwigModule_constants,
    swig_SwigModule_classes,
    swig_SwigModule_namespaces
};

static swig_lua_class* swig_SwigModule_classes[]= {
(...), &_wrap_class_t_hdswUartConf, (...) }

static swig_lua_class _wrap_class_t_hdswUartConf = { "t_hdswUartConf", "t_hdswUartConf", 
   &SWIGTYPE_p_t_hdswUartConf,_proxy__wrap_new_t_hdswUartConf, swig_delete_t_hdswUartConf, swig_t_hdswUartConf_methods, 
   swig_t_hdswUartConf_attributes, 
   &swig_t_hdswUartConf_Sf_SwigStatic, swig_t_hdswUartConf_meta, swig_t_hdswUartConf_bases, swig_t_hdswUartConf_base_names };

static swig_lua_attribute swig_t_hdswUartConf_attributes[] = {
    { "protocolId", _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_protocolId_get, _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_protocolId_set },
    { "speed", _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_speed_get, _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_speed_set },
    { "parity", _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_parity_get, _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_parity_set },
    { "stopBit", _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_stopBit_get, _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_stopBit_set },
    { "wordLength", _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_wordLength_get, _wrap_t_hdswUartConf_wordLength_set },
    {0,0,0}
};
```

But from my interpretor "t_hdswUartConf" data is a table that seems

Thanks beforehand for the interest

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issue for constructor of my object class. SWIG cannot generate _wrap_new_XXX for constructor method. Main problem of my situation is that my object class implement a class with some pure virtual functions and my object class doesn't implement just one of them. SWIG evaluated my object class as abstract class and didn't generate the constructor. At this point, you have 2 option:

1. Implementing all of pure virtual functions results in generating constructor by SWIG automatically.
2. You can also force SWIG to generate constructor for your class (Foo class in example) with below line in your ".i" file:

`%feature("notabstract") Foo;`